# how to fix error in factorial print program?

Tags: python, function, runtime-error, factorial, nonetype

I tried to make this simple *program to find factorial of inputted number*.
But there is an error somewhere i could not figure out:
while i use `raw_input()` function it displays **'none'** output and if i use `input()` function name error is displayed. Help me to find bug .

```
program_active=True
while program_active:
    def fact(n):
        if n==0:
            return 1
        elif not isinstance(n, int):
            while not isinstance(n, int):
                print "Factorial is defined only for Positive integers"
                try:
                    n=int(raw_input())
                except ValueError as ve:
                    pass
        elif n<0:
            print "Factorial is defined only for Positive integers"
        else:
            step1=fact(n-1)
            step2=n*step1
            return step2
    print"input a number to check its factorial"
    n=raw_input()
    print fact(n)
    print
    print
    print
    print "do yo want to run the program again? (y/n)"
    run=raw_input()
    while run[0].upper()!='Y' and run[0].upper()!='N':
        print"****invalid input****"
        run=raw_input('say y/n \n')
    if run[0].upper()=='N':
        program_active=False
        print "goodbye"
```

***here is error while using `raw_input()` function***

```
> input a number to check its factorial 
> 8 
> Factorial is defined only for Positive integers 
> 8 
> None
> 
> 
> 
> do yo want to run the program again? (y/n) n goodbye
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Your code **DOESN'T WORK**.

`8` that you input first is `string` so it will goes through the condition below:

```
elif not isinstance(n, int):
     while not isinstance(n, int):
          print "Factorial is defined only for Positive integers"
          try:
              n=int(raw_input())
          except ValueError as ve:
              pass
```

After that when you input the new `8` which is then converted to `int`, it will break the while loop and go out the `fact()` function without going the part of computing factorial in else condition shown below.

```
else:
     step1=fact(n-1)
     step2=n*step1
     return step2
```

To **FIX** this problem, I would suggest you to move the part of input validation out from the `def fact()`.

CODE:

```
program_active=True
while program_active:
    def fact(n):
        if n==1:
            return n
        elif n==0:
            return 1
        else:
            step1=fact(n-1)
            step2=n*step1
            return step2
    while True:
      print"input a number to check its factorial"
      try:
        n=int(raw_input())
      except:
        print("Factorial is defined only for integer")
        continue
      if n < 1:
        print 'Factorial is defined only for Positive integer'
        continue 

      x = fact(n)
      print x
```

OUTPUT:

```
> input a number to check its factorial 
> 8  
> 40320
```

This code should work.